# Static method, static field and multitheading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have 1 static class and 1 field and 2 methods within it:

```
 static class MyClass{

       private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       private static string SendRequestToServer(int id)
       {
          Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync("some string");
          responseTask.ContinueWith(x => PrintResult(x));
          return "some new value";
        }

        private static void Print(Task<HttpResponseMessage> task)
        {
            Task<string> r = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            r.ContinueWith(resultTask => Console.WriteLine("result is: " + resultTask.Result));
        }
 }
```

The question is, if many threads start using `MyClass` and its methods, would it cause some problems?

Comment: Using static fields in a web application is tricky given the fact that your application might run on several web machines. This is just something you should have in mind when using static fields in web apps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the resources accessed through these methods need to be thread-safe. In your case, they are not. If you look at the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) documentation, it states:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe**.

You're calling an instance method (`client.GetAsync`), which is not be guaranteed to be thread-safe, so that could potentially cause problems for you.

To mitigate this, you could:

- create a new (local) `HttpClient` on each call.
- synchronize access to `client` (e.g. using a lock).

Also, I can't tell you if `PrintResult` will be thread-safe, but `Console.WriteLine` should be thread-safe.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by using lock. Must a locker object by a static variable or an intance one? See @CodeIgnoto example.

Comment: It doesn't directly matter if it is static or instance field -- what matters is that threads entering the *lock* use the same object *reference*. When you use an instance field, all callers will get their own reference, so that won't work, right? :) Consequently, in order to synchronize a static method, you need to lock on a static field.  In your case, you already have such an object, *client*. You can simply lock on *client*. You really don't need a separate lock object.

Comment: But SendRequestToServer was an instance method and if locker was an instance variable, would it be thread safe? I don't think so, since each thread would have its own copy of locker.

Comment: Yes, then it would not be thread-safe because even if it were an instance method, it still accesses a static object (client) that is shared between instances. Therefore, you still need a static object to lock on.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to expect unpredictable results with such setup.You need to have threads access the data in a synchronized manner.A [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement need to used in your case to make sure the execution happens in a synchronized and stable manner.

```
private static Object locker= new Object();

private static string SendRequestToServer(int id)
{ 
  lock(locker)
  {
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync("some string");
    responseTask.ContinueWith(x => PrintResult(x));
    return "some new value";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why locker should be static? If MyClass is not static, can `locker` be an instance variable as well?

Comment: yes if your class is not static,it can be a instance variable

Comment: Really? If many different threads start calling SendRequestToServer(), then there WON'T be any reason of using lock(locker) since each thread is going to have ITS OWN copy of `locker` object.